# Getting weird results from terrain generation sys using 2D Perlin Noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I am trying to make a terrain generation system in Unity, similar to Minecraft's, but using Unity's Perlin Noise function (so only 2D noise).

So I have a 16x16x16 chunk with a `vector2int` that has it's position (so like, if x & z = 0, then the blocks inside are from 0 to 16 in world coordinates).

This is how I'm trying to generate the height map of a chunk:

```cs
    public void generate(float scale) {
        GameObject root = new GameObject("Root");

        // this.z & this.x are the chunk coordinates, size is 16
        for(int z = this.z * size; z < (this.z + size); ++z) {
            for (int x = this.x * size; x < (this.x + size); ++x) {
                float[] coord = new float[2] { (float)x / size * scale, 
                                                (float)z / size * scale };

                Debug.LogFormat("<color='blue'>Perlin coords |</color> x: {0}; y: {1}", coord[0], coord[1]);
                float value = Mathf.PerlinNoise(coord[0], coord[1]);

               // temporary
                GameObject Cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                Cube.transform.position = new Vector3(x, value, z);
                Cube.transform.parent = root.transform;
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

The results are... bad. See for yourself:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: could be obviusly for you....but why is bad? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It looks good, looks just scrunched on the y transform.

```
float value = Mathf.PerlinNoise(coord[0], coord[1]);
```

This is going to give you problems, I'm not sure what coord[0] and coord[1] are but Mathf.PerlinNoise will return a random float between coord[0] and coord[1], so a random float will never be able to produce well aligned tiles.

Better off doing something like

```
int numTilesHigh = Random.Range(0,15);

for (int i = 0; i < numTilesHigh; i++) {
                GameObject Cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                Cube.transform.position = new Vector3(x, <cube height> * i, z);
                Cube.transform.parent = root.transform;
}
```

ps I kind of like your screen shot, not in a minecraft way but it does look cool : - )

Comment: Haha thanks. Well, coord[0] is x divided by 16 and multiplied by a float scale, and coord[1] is the same thing, but with z instead. x & z are integers, because I want the chunks to be in a grid

Comment: keep in mind that mathf.perlinnoise will return a float between 0.0f and 1.0f so if you look at your picture you actually implemented the noise well, you just need to convert the noise into floats by converting different float threshold into solid int or taking a different approach

Comment: convert the noise into int*